# Dynamically created (bootstrap) html table rows - on click event wont trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap table in my view, and table rows are dynamically created, and
after they are created I would like to attach a .onclick event to my rows so in case someone clicks on the row I might highlight it,
I tried it and tested it, and I couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Here is my code:

*1.) First, try - absolutely bad because keeps attaching events on my row, after few clicks there is 5-6-7 alerts popup..*

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>

     $('#TableItems').click(function (e) {
            $('#TableItems tr').click(function (e) {
                alert("Clicked!");
            });
        });

</script>
```

2.) Second try - also not good because view is rendered and **`tr`** are not rendered yet so probably, onclick event can not be attached because when I'm clicking on it
nothing is happening

```
$('#TableItems tr').click(function (e) {
                alert("Damn");
         });
```

Here is my table

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="myTable">
   <table class="table table-striped  jambo_table bulk_action">
     <thead>
       <tr class="headings">
          <th class="column-title">Title </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody id="TableItems"></tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - e.g. `$('#TableItems').on('click', 'tr', function() { ...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You comments are allways awesome mate! It's easy to recognize that you are full of knowledge, It's my pleasure to read you comments!
Thanks one more time!

One more question is, for each of this tr I generated Id = "something" and how I could I get that Id value from this  e object, is that even possible?

Comment: Yes - `var id = $(this).attr('id');` but why are you giving `tr` elements an `id` attribute (does not really make sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because in that dynamically generated table I'm keeping list of customers,
each customer has an Id, and by clicking on a row I want to fill another table with some
other informations..

Comment: You really should be using `data-*` attributes for that - e.g. `<tr data-customerid="...">` (and accessing if with `$(this).data('customerid');`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke why should I do that? That's some convention / best practice or ? I thought it does not matter what kind of attribute I choose there, I guess because we'r talking about Id I should use id attribute..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154449/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-roxypro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.on()` for this

```
$('#TableItems').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    alert("Damn");
});
```

Comment: `document` should be replaced with the closest ancestor which exists when the page is first loaded - i.e. `#TableItems'`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i agree with you but hare OP doesn't mention closest ancestor in question, that's why i used `document`

Comment: Look at the last code snippet showing the html :)

Comment: OK my mistake, I've updated my answer with closest ancestor